# Get the edited value in modal angular bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to get the new value in my modal but I cant get the new value. I tried [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/WtjYirZo9wKBctGomV4w?p=preview) but still no luck. What I see is the difference is that the resolve return was on **$scope**. But when I make my return as **$scope** the **var managementModal** cant see the items.

This is the controller

```
var templateModal = "<div class='modal-header'>" +
        "<button type='button' class='close' ng-click='cancel()'>×</button>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='modal-body'>" +
            "<span>ID</span> <input type='text' readonly='readonly' name='id' value='{{names.id}}' ng-model='editable.id'><br/>" +
            "<span>Approval</span> <input type='text' name='approval' value='{{names.approval}}' ng-model='editable.approval'><br/>" +
            "<span>Status</span> <input type='text' name='status' value='{{names.status}}' ng-model='editable.status'><br/>" +
            "<span>Orderer</span> <input type='text' name='orderer' value='{{names.orderer}}' ng-model='editable.orderer'><br/>" +
            "<span>Creator</span> <input type='text' name='creator' value='{{names.creator}}' ng-model='editable.creator'><br/>" +
            "<span>Production Type</span> <input type='text' name='production_type' value='{{names.production_type}}' ng-model='editable.production_type'><br/>" +
            "<span>First Posting Date</span> <input type='text' name='date' value='{{names.date}}' ng-model='editable.date'><br/>" +
            "<span>Request Price</span> <input type='text' name='budget' value='{{names.budget}}' ng-model='editable.budget'><br/>" +
        "</div>"+
        "<div class='modal-footer'>" +
            "<button type='button' class='close' ng-click='cancel()'>cancel</button>"+
            "<button type='button' class='close' ng-click='update()'>update</button>"+
        "</div>";

$scope.edit = function(data) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            template:templateModal,
            controller: managementModal,
            resolve: {
                items: function() {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function(test){
            console.log(test); // the result is undefined
        });
    };
```

My modal

```
var managementModal = function($scope, $http, $uibModalInstance, items){
    $scope.cancel = function(){
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
    $scope.names = items;
    $scope.editable = items[0];
    console.log($scope.editable); // the result is undefined
    $scope.update = function(){
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    };
};
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td ng-model="id">{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.reg_date}}</td>
    <td><button id="{{x.id}}" ng-click="edit(x)">edit</button></td>
    <td>{{x.approval}}</td>
    <td>{{x.status}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{x.orderer}}</td>
    <td>{{x.creator}}</td>
    <td>{{x.production_type}}</td>
    <td>{{x.date}}</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="firstrequest_{{x.id}}"></td>
    <td>{{x.budget}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Seems to me you're just missing `$uibModalInstance.close($scope.editable)`

Comment: @Phil but the `$scope.editable` is undefined when I `console.log` it

Comment: @Phil also the `modalInstance.result.then(function(test){})` when I `console.log` the `test` it is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do this in the controller (modal)

`$uibModalInstance.close();` to `$uibModalInstance.close($scope.editable);`

and in then change the  `$scope.editable = items[0];` to `$scope.editable = items`
because you are sending an object not an array in items.
here is an [plnk example](https://embed.plnkr.co/CaMWgBTjehK3sThf6NGD/) with your code.

also delete this in your html td

```
<td ng-model="id">{{x.id}}</td>
```

to

```
<td>{{x.id}}</td>
```

Comment: thnx got it so it was undefined because it was an object

Comment: was undefined because you trying to acces into array position where isnt exist. because items wasnt an array.

Comment: in your html you are sending to edit the x. wich is the iterator for de ng-repeat, so it means it was the object. and you trying to acces like an array